# Number of square matrices of order $n$ where each row and each column has at most one $1$

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

> What is the number of square matrices of order $n$ with the property
>   that each row and each column has at most one $1$, and $0$s elsewhere?

For example, when $n=2$, there are $7$ such matrices:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}, 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}, 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Here is an idea I have: So for each $1\leq i \leq n$, we want to pick $i$ rows and fill those rows up with $1$s so that no column has more than one $1$. I think the number of ways of doing this is: ${n\choose i} n(n-1)\cdots (n-i+1)$. So the total number of desired matrices should be 
$$
1+\sum_{i=1}^{n} {n\choose i} n(n-1)\cdots (n-i+1)
$$
The $1$ accounts for the zero matrix. Is this correct? (The formula does work for $n=2$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your formula is correct. You can also write it

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}kn^{\underline k}\;,\tag{1}$$

where $x^{\underline k}$ is the [falling factorial](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer-Symbol). Since $\dbinom{n}k=\dfrac{n^{\underline k}}{k!}$, $(1)$ can be rewritten as

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k^2k!\;.$$

The sequence is [OEIS A002720](http://oeis.org/A002720); the OEIS entry has these formulas, among others, some recurrences, generating functions, and an asymptotic estimate, but there doesn’t seem to be a nice closed form.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :) I especially like the second alternative form $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k^2k!\;$, because it also gives another proof for the count: for each $0\leq k\leq n$, we pick $k$ rows and $k$ columns to fill in with $1$s (which gives a factor of $\binom{n}k^2$), and there is exactly $k!$ ways of doing this.

Comment: @Prism: You’re welcome.